# All-Day outlook event doesn't shown in Sharepoint-Online calender view

Tags: sharepoint, outlook

We have an application that deploys outlook event/appointment/calender (in my case Outlook **All-Day** event) details contained in a xml file to **Office 365** using **sharePoint client API**. It seems everything is working fine like commit to sharepoint but sharepoint doesn't show up that event/appointment/calender in a calender view, yet **recurrent events** are displayed properly in Calender view. Below is snippet of my code to add Event properties in Sharepoint List:

```
  if (isAllDayEvent && (field.Name == "EventDate" || field.Name == "EndDate"))
                                preparedProperties.Add(field.OrigName, val);
else
 dtVal = O365DateTimeUtil.ConvertFromUTCToLocal(clientContext, (DateTime)val);

 if (dtVal != null)
      preparedProperties.Add(field.OrigName, dtVal.Value);
```

So what I am missing in my code or do i need to particularly configure in SharePoint?

Your help or suggestion will warmly be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Check EventType of event.  It depends of behavior of event.

Refer to : http://aspnetguru.wordpress.com/2007/06/01/understanding-the-sharepoint-calendar-and-how-to-export-it-to-ical-format/